# How to display few objects of the same class i Mustache template language

Tags: java, html, mustache

In the class Tg there is Public ListField1, which includes class Tzzz. I need that Tzzz was displayed in HTML so much times as is stated in List. There is HMTL code that displays one Tzzz:

```
<div class="section3">
        <span class="section3_label1">{{tv_stopH}}</span><span class="section3_label2">{{tv_sch}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1">
    <div class="section3_1_textblock1">
        <span class="label_alt">{{arri}}</span><br />
        {{tv_add}}
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1_textblock2">
        <span class="label_alt">{{cont}}</span><br />
        {{tv_cont}}
    </div>
    <div class="section3_1_textblock1">
        {{#pic1}}
        <span class="label_alt">{{tv_refName1}}:</span>&nbsp;{{tv_ref1}}<br />
        {{/pic1}}        
    </div>
```

Class Tg:

```
public class Tg
{
    public List<Tzzz> Field1;

    public String Value1;
    public String Value2;
    ............
```

Class Tzzz:

```
public class Tzzz
{
public Integer tv_stopH;
public String tv_sch;
public String arri;
public String cont;
........
```

JAVA code for one object Tzzz:

```
    Template tmpl = Mustache.compiler().escapeHTML(false).compile(template);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    .......
    value = tzzz.tv_stopH;
    data.put("tv_stopH", value);

    value = tzzz.tv_sch;
    data.put("tv_sch", value);

    value = tzzz.arri;
    data.put("arri", value);

    value = tzzz.tv_add;
    data.put("tv_add", value);

    value = tzzz.cont;
    data.put("cont", value);


    if(tzzz.tv_refName1.length() > 0)
    {
        data.put("pic1", True);

        value = tzzz.tv_refName1;
        data.put("tv_refName1", value);

        value = tzzz.tv_ref1;
        data.put("tv_ref1", value);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `{{#list_key_name}}...{{/list_key_name}}`.

So if you have a variable `List<SomeObject> foo` and you add that to the `Map<String, Object> params;` `params.put("foo", foo)`, then the template would look like this.

```
<ul>
    {{#foo}}
    <li><!--interpolate values from SomeObject --></li>       
    {{/foo}}
</ul>
```

These things are explained in the [documentation](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html). It should work across different implementations, unless the port for some reason has decided to break the "spec".